# Performance when using RabbitMQ with dynamic queues and persistant messages

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I would like to implement dynamic queues with RabbitMQ and create one persistante queue per user I have.

I wonder if the RabbitMQ will not loose in performence if I have a large number of messages that stay into the broker in time and this multiplied per user ?

Comment: You should ask general questions about RabbitMQ on the rabbitmq-users google group, where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out. They look here from time to time, but you will likely get a quicker answer there. There is not a separate copy of a message per user.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it existance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for Rabbitmq that allows you to test and see what it's performance is like here:
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/

Comment: Thank you. I add it in my favorites

Comment: If this helped, please make sure to upvote or mark as answer.